# this.menu.deactivate is not a function when using autocomplete with django-selectable

Tags: django, jquery-ui

I've used `django-selectable` to search on `Company` model by `name` and have this `lookup`:

```
class FruitLookup(ModelLookup):
    model = Company
    search_fields = ('name__icontains', )

    def get_item_label(self, item):
        return u"%s,%s" % (item.name, item.logo.url)


from selectable.registry import registry    
registry.register(FruitLookup)
```

in `views.py`:

```
companyForm=FruitForm()
return render_to_response('PersonHub/addCompanyPosition.html',{'companyForm':companyForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in template:

```
<form id="frmCompanyPositionAdd"  action="" method="POST" style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px' >
{{companyForm}}
</form>
```

in template header:

```
function formatLabel(label, item) {
    var data = label.split(',');
    $('.ui-autocomplete').css({ 'float': 'right','text-align':'right'});
    return "<span><span>"+data[0]+"</span>&nbsp;<span><img class='size32' src='"+data[1]+"' /></span></span>";
}
$('#id_autocomplete').djselectable('option', 'formatLabel', formatLabel);
```

I keep the ID of selected company in a hidden input with id=`id_chosen_company`:

```
$( "#id_autocomplete" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {jQuery('#id_chosen_company').val(ui.item.id);} );
```

but when I enter `company name` in input with id=`id_autocomplete` I get this error in firefox:

```
this.menu.deactivate is not a function

this.menu.deactivate();
```

and get this error in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'deactivate'
```

while the result list in json format is returned,but the result list is not shown and I get mentioned errors!!
**Note:** error occures in `jquery.dj.selectable.js`.

Comment: What version of django-selectable and what version of jQuery/jQuery UI? This sounds like https://bitbucket.org/mlavin/django-selectable/issue/73 which was fixed back in Oct.

Comment: jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery-ui 1.9.2 and django-selectable 0.6.2

Comment: tnx,I used jQuery-ui version 8 and It's working :)